# java raises an SSLHandshakeException even if the root certificate in the trust store

Tags: java, ssl

The following java code:

```
new URL("https://www.limagrain.com/").openStream()
```

raises the following error:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException thrown: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

However, the root certificate used by this site ([Thawte Primary Root CA - G3](https://www.thawte.com/roots/)) is present in java's trust store, and the site displays without problems in browsers.

Checking the site on [Qualys SSL checker](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=limagrain.com) gives a warning about an intermediate certificate marked as *extra download*.

How to make java download the intermediate certificates automatically ?

Answer (score 11):

### Solution

Set the system property `com.sun.security.enableAIAcaIssuers` to `true`.

```
System.setProperty("com.sun.security.enableAIAcaIssuers", "true");
```

See Oracle's Java PKI guide: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/certpath/CertPathProgGuide.html#AppB.

Comment: Thanks for not only saying what to do, but also how to actually do it.

Answer (score 3):

As, You are using secure channel https. Only, root certificate is not enough. Either you would require to have Root and CA or complete certificate chain.

**Part - I**

Support for the Authority Information Access (AIA) Extension

> Support for the caIssuers access method of the Authority Information
>   Access extension is available. It is disabled by default for
>   compatibility and can be enabled by setting the system property 
>   com.sun.security.enableAIAcaIssuers to the value true.

If set to true, Sun's PKIX implementation of CertPathBuilder uses the information in a certificate's AIA extension (in addition to  CertStores that are specified) to find the issuing CA certificate, provided it is a URI of type ldap, http, or ftp.

> Note: Depending on your network and firewall setup, it may be
>   necessary to also configure your networking proxy servers as described
>   in the [networking
>   documentation(http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/net/properties.html).

**Part - II**

Below are steps how to import certificate chain in java certs manually

1. Open https://www.limagrain.com/ in Google chrome then Press F12.
2. Select Security Tab ad Select certificate Path as highlighted.

[image]

3. Go to details tab and click on Export to file. Select Base 64 encoded type.

[image]

4. Give the certification filename and Click on Next and Next.

[image]

5. Open the certificate and see if certificate chain is exported properly.
   [image]
6. GO to %JAVA_HOME%/jre/lib/security in command.exe
7. Import Certificate chain using below command.

   keytool -importcert -file limagrain.cer -alias limagrain -keystore  cacerts -storepass changeit

NOTE: make sure certificate path is correct.

8. Accept the certificate in cecerts by writing "yes".

Comment: your insights were so helpful ! "complete certificate chain" is needed (or the certificate itself but this is far less durable solution as server certificates change more often compared to the root ones).